# How to set java version in the Azure hdinsight while creating a cluster

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, azure-devops, azure-hdinsight

We are creating a cluster in Azure we need to upgrade the java version.
Here is the command -
`az hdinsight create --name test_cluster --resource-group $resource_group --type spark --cluster-tier Standard --component-version Spark=$component_version --headnode-size $headnode_size --location $location --http-password $http_password --http-user $http_user --ssh-user $ssh_user --ssh-public-key "$ssh_pub_key" --storage-account $storage_account_name --storage-account-key $storage_account_key --storage-container $storage_container --subnet $subnet_name --vnet-name $vnet_name --version $version --workernode-count $workernode_count --workernode-size $workernode_size --tags Name=$cluster_name`

Do we have an option to set the java version ?

Comment: I think you cannot do that. There is no option for that. If you are using the Azure infrastructure you do not install those products, so you cannot change any version.

Comment: It seems that your cluster type is "Spark", so I believe your only option is upgrading the Cluster Version of that.  Not Java specifically.

Comment: What version of java it uses default ?

Answer (score 0):

```
`Do we have an option to set the java version ?`
```

No, We don't have an option to set the java version using Azure cli cmdlet.

We can only update the tags of the specified HDInsight cluster using below cmdlet.

```
az hdinsight update --name MyCluster --resource-group rg --tags key=value
```

For more information about the supported `az` commands to Manage HDInsight resources, refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/hdinsight?view=azure-cli-latest).